# How to remove a word to another word from string using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

How can I remove a part of a string from one word to another word using regular expressions?

For example, I have a string like

```
String s = "<html><body> this is test </body></html>"
```

In the above string I have to remove the part from the starting `<body>` tag to the ending `</body>` tag, and the value in between will be determined dynamically, the output should be `s="<html></html>"`.

Comment: What are all those single quotes and forward slashes doing in your string? Are they supposed to be in there or are they an effort on your part to escape the `<` chars? Please edit your question and have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to see how to format your question properly.

Comment: try to improve your question. It is not understandable what you want to say...

Comment: @Bart I've just removed those elements; judging by the desired output being written originally as "pure" HTML tags (and thus parsed as such by Markdown), I'm assuming that the OP originally wrote the whole post as such and then tried to insert arbitrary characters to stop the tags being parsed.  The revised version is more consistent with a desired output of `<html></html>` too.

Comment: This is obviously a contrived example and can't be what you actually need to do. What is it you *really*  want to do? Remove a specified tag including its contents? If so, could there be multiple tags? If so, do you want to remove all of them or just certain ones? Which ones? Could there be nested tags? Could there be comments or quotes inside the string you're parsing? Could those comments/strings possibly contain text that looks like a tag? Etc. etc. etc. - you need to exactly define your problem.

Comment: `the output should be s="<html></html>"`, then `String s= "<html></html>"` does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something here, you can use:

```
s = s.replaceFirst("<body>.+</body>", "");
```

Of course, with your example, you might just as well use

```
s = s.substring(0, 6) + s.substring(s.length() - 7, s.length());
```

to avoid a costly regex.

Comment: FWIW, I'd advise using a non-greedy regex, i.e. `s = s.replaceFirst("<body>.+?</body>", "");`, just in case the tag-ish thing he wants to replace is not a single occurrence

Comment: @riffraff: I'd agree for a general case, but I think greedy makes more sense for this absurd scenario, as there should only be one pair of `body` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after editing HTML or better XHTML and/or XML use DOM. It's not very good idea trying to do that with regular expressions.

If you have/want to use regexp:

If you want to remove from `HERE` to `THERE`, have you thought of cases like these `HERE A HERE B THERE C THERE`? Simple non greedy match will not behave as "expected" removing the inner HERE to THERE, but will result in `C THERE`.

Basically what you have to do is to find a `THERE` and then go to left to find first `HERE` so `s/(.*)HERE.*?THERE/\1/` (using PCRE syntax) should do the trick and leave `HERE A C THERE`. Repeat to get rid of that too. However, this will not work with global substitution replacing all occurrences. For such usecase use the algo:

```
while (found) {
  find a first `THERE` and then go to left to find first `HERE` \
  with regexps or without.
}
```